# preg_replace_callback of url in textarea cuts off at underscore or colon

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Not sure how to proceed to allow or prevent snipping at **underscore** and **colon** in urls in this preg_replace. Also not sure what other special characters I might be missing that will snip the url

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', function($m) {
   return '<a href="' . $m[1] . '" target="_blank">' . substr($m[1], 0, 75) . '</a>';
}, $text);
```

The text link may appear as https://something.com/something_something:moresomething but it only links the https://something.com/something _something:moresomething. I used both symbols in this as example but it does it individually too.

Comment: What do you mean by "snip the url"? Can you update the question with example strings that the pattern should match and your desired result or what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Thefourthbird When generating a url it does not include anything after an underscore or colon. I will try to show above.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon in this part `[-\w/_\.:]*` but as you only use `$m[1]` in the callback code you can simplify the pattern and omit using capture groups at all and make use of the full match with `$m[0]`

**Note** that you don't have to escape the dot `\.` in a character class, and `\w` also matches `_` so you don't have to add that separately to the character class.

```
https?://(?:[-\w.]+)+(?::\d+)?(?:/(?:[-\w/.:]*(?:\?\S+)?)?)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `https?://` Match the protocol with an optional `s`
- `(?:[-\w.]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching one of the listed in the character class
- `(?::\d+)?` Optionally match `:` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `/` Match literally
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[-\w/.:]*` Optionally repeat matching one of the listed in the character class
    - `(?:\?\S+)?` Optionally match `?` and 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

For example

```
$text = "https://something.com/something_something:moresomething";
$pattern = '@https?://(?:[-\w.]+)+(?::\d+)?(?:/(?:[-\w/.:]*(?:\?\S+)?)?)?@';
$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) {
    return '<a href="' . $m[0] . '" target="_blank">' . substr($m[0], 0, 75) . '</a>';
}, $text);

echo $text;
```

Output

```
<a href="https://something.com/something_something:moresomething" target="_blank">https://something.com/something_something:moresomething</a>
```